# Internaly hosted alternative to cloudbased nobackend solution like Firebase

Tags: node.js, cloud-hosting, javascript, json

In an environment where I can't use a cloud based service like Firebase, I'm looking for recommendation for an internally hosted nobackend solution. I could use node or meteor but really am just wanting to get functionality to Firebase, without spending resources on server-side development.

Any ideas? I imagine node or meteor can do essentially the the same thing as Firebase but it ends up becoming a hand-rolled backed again.

Comment: How do you envision a no-backend self-hosted-backend working, exactly?

Comment: @ceejayoz I just want json persistence and auto push to connected clients similarly to how Firebase works. Also need good authentication functionality.

Comment: You're unlikely to find something like this that is management-free.

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah thats likely